# combining css classes in css file

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following css rule:

```
.blah { Rules }
```

and I use it as such

```
<div class="blah">
```

Now suppose, somewhere in my doc I need to add `margin-bottom: 10px` to one of these divs with class name blah so I can make it as specific as possible,

Should I declare it as

```
.blah.mar-bot-blah { margin-bottom: 10px; }
or 
.blah .mar-bot-blah { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

to use it as `<div class="blah mar-bot-blah">`

Comment: FYI, using a space in between classes is for descendants. So you would use second example if .mar-bot-blah is a child element of the .blah element.

Answer (score 5):

Declare it as:

```
.blah.mar-bot-blah { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

It will match elements that have both the classes `.mar-bot-blah` and `.blah`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it really specific, I would use your first solution.
(Warning: IE6 Can't handle this!)

In most cases it should suffice to just use 
    .mar-bot-blah { margin-bottom: 10px; }
so you can re-use this setting in other classes as well.